# Como faço para passar uma parâmetro de uma função na hora de chamar a propriedade de um objeto dentro da função? em js

Tags: javascript, html, css, funções, objetos

Estou treinando html/css e javascript desenvolvendo uma pokedéx(catalogo de pokémons) usando a pokeapi, e to tendo uma certa dificuldade em chamar uma propriedade de um objeto usando uma função como parâmetro, segue o objeto:

```
const colors = {
insect: "lightgreen",
grass: "green",
fairy: "pink",
normal: "lightgrey",
}
```

a função:

```
const changecolor = (type) =>{
containerEl.style.borderColor = (colors.(pretendo chamar o parâmetro type aqui, mas não sei como))
}
```

como estou tentando chamar a função:

```
changecolor("grass")
```

como eu teria que fazer para conseguir passar o type como o nome da propriedade que quero buscar no objeto colors?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi você está tentando acessar o valor da chave `'grass'` mas isso não será possível pois quando você busca dentro da sua função `colors.type` o javascript vai procurar alguma **chave** dentro do seu objeto **colors** que se chame **type**, neste caso ele não está referenciando o parâmetro.
A maneira que eu sugiro fazer seria:

```
const changecolor = (type) => {
containerEl.style.borderColor = colors[type];
}
changecolor('grass')
```

Dessa maneira você consegue acessa a chave dentro do objeto.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu apliquei no meu código e funcionou perfeitamente, eu queria dar upvote na sua resposta mas não posso ainda, mas realmente me ajudou muito, vlw.